# Apparently, Stored Procedure syntax is harder to understand than I anticipated

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So basically I'm trying to replicate this query as a stored procedure.

```
Use ThisDB   
  SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName ,     
         sum(UnitPrice * Quantity) as 'Total Sales',   
         YEAR(OrderDate) as SalesYear   
  From Employees e   
      Join Orders o on o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID    
      join [Order Details] od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID   
      Group by LastName +' ' +FirstName, YEAR(OrderDate)
      Order by 'Total Sales' desc
```

**Edit:** I noticed that the old query was gonna fail, but that don't change too much **/edit**

Unfortunately, I haven't found any good examples that help me translate what I know about queries to stored procedure syntax.  Here is what i understand so far:

```
Use ThisDB;
go
CREATE PROCEDURE empSalesByYear as @Emp OUT  
BEGIN  
     Set Emp = (SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName ,   
            TotalSales = sum([Order Details].UnitPrice * [OrderDetails].Quantity),
        YEAR(orders.OrderDate) as SalesYear   
             From Employees e  
         Join Orders o on o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
             join [Order Details] od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
             group by FirstName , LastName
             Order by TotalSales desc)  
END  
GO
```

Predictably, `SQL server` give me the finger when I type all this in. . .

My goal here is a stored procedure that takes zero input parameters and outputs a table like the first query.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the error message perhaps?  Did you realise you have `REATE PROCEDURE` rather than `CREATE PROCEDURE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comment, you can just do:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_GetEmpSalesByYear AS

SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName ,
sum(UnitPrice * Quantity) as 'Total Sales',
YEAR(OrderDate) as SalesYear
From ThisDB..Employees e
Join ThisDB..Orders o on o.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
join ThisDB..[Order Details] od on od.OrderID = o.OrderID
Group by LastName, FirstName Order by 'Total Sales' desc

GO
```

..unless you wanted to return a table output parameter?

(Removed the USE, missed that.. now using db..table format)

Comment: You cannot use `USE` within a stored proc (nor function nor trigger)

Comment: No idea if I'll need to return a table output parameter.  But that looks easy.  I found an example for that.  But this looks good.  I'm still trying to grasp if I ever have to do a subquery cause I just noticed my query won't work with SalesYear.  I gotta include that in a subquery. . .

Comment: @Damien: Now that I think about, I do remember reading something about not being able to select tables from other databases in Procs. . .

Comment: @surfasb - you can access tables in other databases (or even on other servers) using three (or four) part names. What you can't do is switch database context within the procedure (by using `USE ThisDB`), as Kieren currently has.

Comment: @Damien: That doesn't sound too hard.

Comment: I didn't go with a subquery, cause I still gotta look for a good example of that for stored procedures.  It looks like it doesn't exactly translate so I gotta read so more.  But that's a whole nother question. . .